# what is the sufficient and necessary condition to do Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

i know there is a sufficient condition: absolutely integrable & piecewise smooth, i want to know what is the sufficient and necessary condition to do Fourier transform for a function.

and what is the space of all function can do Fourier transform? What are the characteristics of this space?

Comment: Tempered distributions ... but I suppose you don't know about that?

Comment: @LL3.14 no, i don't know that. can you say the concepts(tempered distributions) easily? or can you give me more key words to search?